# Typescript exporting key/value object with react component as value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a .tsx file and I'm looking to export a object that contains a key/value pair. The value is going to be a react component that is used in another file.

I'm going to have multiple key/value pairs, but I'm showing one for the moment.

object.tsx

```
import { DummyComponent } from 'components/DummyComponent';

export interface DummyComponentProps {
  [key: string]: React.Component<{}> | undefined;
}

export const DummyComponentObject: DummyComponentProps = {
  dummy: <DummyComponent/>,
};
```

I'm getting the following error, and I don't know what the problem is?

> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<{}, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 2 more.ts(2740)
> object.tsx(4, 3): The expected type comes from this index signature.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that you're assigning an *element* to `dummy` rather than a *component*. Remember: components are functions that return elements. In this case, your component is `DummyComponent`, not `<DummyComponent />`. So I believe this should work:

```
export const DummyComponentObject: DummyComponentProps = {
  dummy: DummyComponent,
};
```

You could also do this, although you don't need to:

```
export const DummyComponentObject: DummyComponentProps = {
  dummy: () => <DummyComponent />,
};
```